# OAuth2.0 linkin user accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid

I am developing an application which implements OAuth2.0 for internal authentication. Mainly what it's use for is the never expiring jwt access_token. 
In the token there are some claims about the user info, like user id.

Now there is a new requirement, need to integrate with PingOne trough OpenId connect.

So now the application should enable access with an other token as well - doesn't have claims which my my application builds logic on - also I need to avoid the situation, where 2 account belongs to the same person, one created with password, one created with SSO.

What is the common best practice to handle the situation like this?

My current thoughts:

- If the user authenticated with SSO and the user doesn't exist with the email address, it needs to be created.
- The PingOne token needs to be changed to an other token, to the old style JWT token, that has the internal user id claim in it. So I need an endpoint, which accepts the PintOne token, and change it to the current one.

Is it a good / secure approach?

Thanks.